# Simple Bash Programming

Tags: bash, unix

I am a newbie to BASH so please dont mind my stupid questions because I am not able to get any good sources to learn that.

I want to create a script to display filename and its size. This is what the code is like

```
filename=$1
if [ -f $filename ]; then
    filesize=`du -b $1`
    echo "The name of file is $1"
    echo "Its size is $filesize"
else
    echo "The file specified doesnot exists"
fi
```

The output is like this

```
$ ./filesize.sh aa
The name of file is aa
Its size is 88  aa
```

But in the last line I don't want to show the name of the file. How do I do that ?
I want to do the same thing using wc as well.

Comment: Here's one very good source http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*All* levels of question are accepted here.

You can use `awk` to only get the first field:

```
du -b /path/to/file | awk '{print $1}'
```

Your script would then be something like:

```
filename=$1
if [ -f ${filename} ]; then
    filesize=$(du -b ${filename} | awk '{print $1}')
    echo "The name of file is ${filename}"
    echo "Its size is ${filesize}"
else
    echo "The file specified does not exists"
fi
```

You'll notice I've changed a couple of other things as well:

- I prefer `$(X)` to `X` for capturing output of command simply because they're easier to nest.
- If you've already put `$1` into `$filename`, you may as well use `$filename` from that point on (the `$1` in the `awk` is a different beast).
- I prefer to put all my variables inside `${}` so that it's obvious to both the reader and the shell that `${var}X` is `$var` appended with `X`, rather than $varX being the non-existent ${varX}.

These are really personal preferences but, as with all my personal preferences, I consider them best practices for the entire IT industry :-)

Answer (score 3):

Use stat(1)

```
filename=$1
if [ -f $filename ]; then
    filesize=`stat -c %s $1`
    echo "The name of file is $1"
    echo "Its size is $filesize"
else
    echo "The file specified doesnot exists"
fi
```

See also [man 1 stat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stat)

Comment: I like this solution the best: It employs only one external tool (stat), unlike other solutions which use two.

Answer (score 1):

```
filesize=`du -b $1 | cut -f 1`
```

`cut -f 1` splits its input by tabs and then outputs the first field (i.e. it returns each line of `du`'s output up to the fist tab character.).

Answer (score 0):

You could use **awk** to split the output of du at the first space, as follows:

```
filesize=`du -b $1 | awk '{ print $1; }'`
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `du -b $1` use `du -b $1 | cut -f 1`. It will only include the first field of output of du command, therefore only reporting the size of the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk to pick out the first column of data.

```
filesize=`du -b $1 | awk '{print $1}'`
```